# Upload form data on one server, image on another server

Tags: apache2, php, upload, image, imagemagick

On a site (like a social network) where users upload images together with text data like image_title, user_id, etc; Using Apache, PHP, MySQL...

On the submitted form, I would like to upload all images to a dedicated image server by default. I am not sure **what is the best practice** to do that...

Does it work to make the form send data on two different servers ? Is this a good practice ? I see it works to trigger the `submit()` on a second form when one is submitted.

I could also upload on the main site's server then move the image but this would be against the purpose of a dedicated image server, I want to also take off the incoming traffic load from main site.

Instead of two forms, would it be a good practice to upload image first, get the "OK" reply and then submit the text data ?

I don't like Amazon S3 for this, tried it, too slow from my tests.

Answer (score 1):

there are three options:

1. upload form and images with splitted ajax requests. perhaps if you have two different servers (form server, images server) you need a cross domain service on one of these to redirect that traffic. it is not possible to call different servers from a jquery/javascript ajax on client side.
2. implement a service which is able to recieve both (form, images) and sharing out the data.. e.g. forward formular to server1 and lay down images at server2
3. perform a request sequence.. first submit e.g. the formular to your backend. if the callback is OK send the images via a e.g. cross_domain.php (see option1) to your dedicated image server..

IMHO there is no way to send data from client to multiple servers without redirecting traffic via your backend!

Answer (score 0):

I would not split the submit into two submits to different servers. I don't think that it would be against the purpose of a dedicated image server to handle the upload/validation of the images on a different server. If you need a dedicated image server i believe it is most common that the image server does really nothing else than serving static files via http.
In my experience s3 is suited quite well for that purpose. If it really is to slow for you, have a look at cloudfront! An alternative would be a separate Server with nginx or lighttp, perhaps with varnish in front, that is optimized for serving static image files.

Before you try to separate the upload/validation of a single form-POST or even only the image-POSTs to a different server i would prefer to try to scale the whole service onto multiple servers.

Comment: Well this upload on a different server IS supposed to be the start of my scaling; after this, I have the MySQL database, is easy to move it to a dedicated server and replicate it, then all I have are a few php files that just work with the image server and db servers, these php files can easy be spread on multiple servers (probably by DNS).